# How can I display values from Android Studio profiler/performance on my app?

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, android-profiler

I used the Android Studio profiler to check how the values of CPU, memory and energy change during the execution of an app I'm developing. I wonder if there is any way I could display these values, for instance, the energy consumed and CPU load on my APP?

[This](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/energy-profiler) is some of the documentation I checked and it doesn't say anything about it.

If there is any other way to display performance values on the app without using the profiler, I could also use that!

Answer (score 0):

The energy data presented in Android Studio Profilers are based on a mathematical model that takes CPU utilization, network activity, location activity, etc. as inputs. The source code is [here](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:transport-database/src/main/java/com/android/tools/datastore/energy/PowerProfile.java?q=PowerProfile.java) in case you are interested.

The CPU load is calculated from /proc/* files. The code is [here](https://cs.android.com/android-studio/platform/tools/base/+/mirror-goog-studio-main:profiler/native/perfd/cpu/cpu_usage_sampler.cc).

That said, the profilers collect the data sometimes as the shell user, sometimes as the app. Your app may not have the permission to access them.

Comment: Thank you. I don't have access to those links. Are they published anywhere else?

Comment: Sorry I accidentally provided the wrong links. I have  updated my post. Please give the new links a try. Please let me know if they are still broken.